# Solving a continuous space, discrete time walk

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, biophysics, stochastic-processes

I posted this in the math forum but thought that putting it here might be helpful too. So here goes:

Consider a random walk starting from position $x_0$ on the $1D$ line that takes steps (of step length $r_x$ which is a random variable that depends on its position) at discrete times steps. For this, we can write down the master equation for the probability density $P(x,t)$ of finding the walker at position $x$ at time $t$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
P(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}M(x,x')P(x',t-1)dx'
\end{equation}
where $M(x,x')$ is the probability density of finding the walker the $x$ given that at the previous time-step, it was at position $x'$.

Say we take $M(x,x')$ of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\Delta t}}e^{\frac{[x-x'(1-\lambda \Delta t)]^2}{4\Delta t}}$ where $\lambda$ and $\Delta t$ are parameters of the model.

Can the RHS of our master equation be considered as a convolution? I would like to solve for $P(x,t)$ and if yes, then using a Fourier transform/Generating function, I can write the convolution as a product and solve easily.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: cross post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3422636/87420

Comment: If you rescale $x'$ such that $M(x,x') = M(x-x')$ (by doing a variable substitution in the integral), you will get a convolution that you can FT. The point is that it will relate $P(k,t)$ with $P(\alpha k, t-1)$

Comment: @yu-v But relating $P(k,t)$ with $P(\alpha k, t-1)$ would not be very useful, right?

I guess my best bet is to exploit the fact that the sum of Gaussians is a Gaussian and try to deduce the distribution recursively.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I am not completely sure that it is not useful. You get an equation of the sort $P(k,t) = M(k) P(\alpha k, t-1)$ from which you get  (I think? I am at work and can't work the details out)  $P(k,t) = [ \prod_j M(\alpha^j k) ] P(\alpha^N k, 0)$ with $N$ the number of time-steps. And you know the distribution at $t=0$. I could be wrong, though :)

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I concur.